# When or use a many-to-many relation in a database?

Tags: relational-database

I want to know in what situations we create many to many relation. What is the need of doing such?

Comment: Scenario: In your workplace ...... There are many projects and there are many employees . SO you want the relation to be ONE_EMPLOYEE can work in MANY_Projects and "Vice Versa" EACH_PROJECT can have Many_Employees

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick search goes a long way. Though the following is for MS Access, the concept is the same for any relational database.

Via: [office.microsoft.com - Create a many-to-many relationship](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-relationships-for-a-new-database-RZ101772998.aspx?section=9):

> You have a many-to-many relationship when a single record in one table
>   can relate to many records in another, and a single record in that
>   second table can also relate to many records in the first. For
>   example, say your company has several types of computers and several
>   technicians, with each technician certified to work on some, but not
>   all, of the computers. Each technician can be related to more than one
>   computer, and in turn, each computer can be related to more than one
>   technician.
>
> To track who can work on a given machine, you create a many-to-many
>   relationship by adding the primary keys from both sides of the
>   relationship to a third table, called a junction or link table. In
>   other words, a many-to-many relationship is really just a pair of
>   one-to-many relationships.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful explanation. I have a question. I can see in the screenshot that some rows from both tables are present. Is that even necessary? I'd think that any required information could be retrieved just with a direct reference to the chosen table.row (left table or right table, as seen in the screenshot).